# Display inline block not displaying the divs in the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

My two divs : `form-panel` and `data-panel` are not in the same line. How to align them in the same line using `display:inline-block` Please check the code given below. I have used display:inline-block on both the panels but still the alignment of both the divs is not same.

```js
var data=[
{"name":"Test Task#1","date":"12/01/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#2","date":"12/02/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#3","date":"12/03/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#4","date":"12/04/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#5","date":"12/05/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#6","date":"12/06/2012","assigned":"John Doe"},
{"name":"Test Task#7","date":"12/07/2012","assigned":"John Doe"}
];
function load() { 
 var tableData="";
 var stage=$("#stage");
 $.each(data,function(i){
          stage.prepend('<tr><td>  ' + data[i].name + '</td>'+'<td> ' + data[i].date+ '</td>'+'<td style="width:30px;"></td><td> ' + data[i].assigned+ '</td></tr>');
   });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#sfrm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 showValues();
 
});
function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serializeArray();
    var dateArr = str[1].value.split('-');
    dateArr.push(dateArr.shift());
    var date=dateArr.join('/')
 $( "#stage" ).prepend( '<tr><td>  ' + str[0].value + '</td>'+'<td> ' + date + '</td>'+'<td style="width:30px;"></td><td> ' + str[2].value + '</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: arial;
}
.background_panel{
 width: 1024px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background-color: #e2e2e2;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 85px;
 overflow: auto;
}
h1{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.main_panel{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="text"],input[type="date"]{
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 90%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
 background-color: #ececec;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type="submit"]{
 background-color: #434343;
 border: 1px solid #ececec;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.content{
 position: relative;
}
.form_panel{
 width: 47%;
 padding: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
}
.data_panel{ 
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 48%;
 padding: 10px;
}
.clear{
 clear: left;
}
.main_header{
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  min-height: 120px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
hr{
  width: 3px;
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -12px;
}
table{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 3px solid #dedede;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
td{
 padding: 9px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
 background-color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Spino Tutorials" />
 <title>Task Tracker</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">

<div class="background_panel">
 <div class="main_header">
  <h1>Task Tracker</h1>
  <span>v2.0</span>
 </div>
 <div style="vertical-align:top">
  <div class="form_panel">
   <h3>Create a Task</h3>
   <form id="sfrm">
    Task Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="task" ><br><br>
    Date<br>
    <input type="date" name="date"><br><br>
    Assigned To<br>
   
    <input type="text" name="assigned" ><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="target" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="data_panel">
   <h3>Exsisting Tasks</h3>
   <table id="stage" style="table-layout: fixed; max-height: 350px;"></table>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="clear">
   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: this div `<div style="vertical-align:top">` might need `inline-block` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `vertical-align: top` on both divs rather than their parent.